# ask me for select syntax sql in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
id.    goods    quantities 
2      milk     1 
3      copies   1
2      milk     1
```

how to display with sql syntax be ..

```
Id      goods     quantities 
2       milk      2  
3       coffies   1
```

because there is a duplicate of milk then the amount is added.?

Ask answer ..thaks

Comment: This post needs to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You want to group the rows by `id` and `goods`, and you want the values to be summed up, so the SQL functions you're looking for are `GROUP BY` and `SUM`:

```
select  id, goods, sum(quantities)
from    yourTable
group by id, goods
```

Comment: should not use distince? because there is a duplicate of milk

Comment: No, you're already grouping the rows that have the same `id` and `goods` values, so there's no need to add `distinct`. Why don't you just try by yourself though? It's the best way to find out :)